# How to increment the row of uipicker when it is scrolled in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIPicker which i'm developing through an array. In my array i am currently saving 10 values in it and number of rows of UIPicker counting array, then Picker shows 10 values in it .But my problem is, when i scroll the UIPicker, i want that after the 10th row is scrolled new rows should be automatically added with values filled in it. Actually i have added picker in an action sheet.This is my code through which i am loading data in picker.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{   
    currentData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

 #pragma mark  UIPickerViewDelegate Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    int count;  
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"picker"])
    {
        count = [currentData count];
    }

    return count;
}
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *string;
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"picker"])
    {
        NSString *str = @"miles";
        //string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[currentData objectAtIndex:row],@"%@",str];
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" @"%@",[currentData objectAtIndex:row],str];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }   
    return string;
}
-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 300;
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    select = YES;       
    if([barItems objectAtIndex:2]!=0)
    {                   
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"picker"])
    {
        sessoTxt.text = [currentData objectAtIndex:row];
    }                   
}
    else{
        sessoTxt.text = @"Select";
    }    
}
```

How to increment the row of picker dynamically when it is scrolled after the last array value.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might check http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=6120638&highlight=UIPickerView#post6120638